# Replace Bad words using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to create a bad word filter method that I can call before every insert and update to check the string for any bad words and replace with "[Censored]".

I have an SQL table with has a list of bad words, I want to bring them back and add them to a List or string array and check through the string of text that has been passed in and if any bad words are found replace them and return a filtered string back.

I am using C# for this.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to update/insert the censored strings without keeping a copy of the uncensored string. You will most likely have to adapt your wordlist and replacement strategy for many iterations until it is 'right enough' and should not risk to destroy your data in the meantime

Comment: Gave you a vote just for calling them 'Bad Words'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please see this "clbuttic" (or for your case cl[Censored]ic) article before doing a string replace without considering word boundaries:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

**Update**

Obviously not foolproof (see article above - this approach is so easy to get around or produce false positives...) or optimized (the regular expressions should be cached and compiled), but the following will filter out whole words (no "clbuttics") and simple plurals of words:

```
const string CensoredText = "[Censored]";
const string PatternTemplate = @"\b({0})(s?)\b";
const RegexOptions Options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

string[] badWords = new[] { "cranberrying", "chuffing", "ass" };

IEnumerable<Regex> badWordMatchers = badWords.
    Select(x => new Regex(string.Format(PatternTemplate, x), Options));

string input = "I've had no cranberrying sleep for chuffing chuffings days -
    the next door neighbour is playing classical music at full tilt!";

string output = badWordMatchers.
   Aggregate(input, (current, matcher) => matcher.Replace(current, CensoredText));

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Gives the output:

> I've had no [Censored] sleep for [Censored] [Censored] days - the next door neighbour is playing classical music at full tilt!

Note that "classical" does not become "cl[Censored]ical", as whole words are matched with the regular expression.

**Update 2**

And to demonstrate a flavour of how this (and in general basic string\pattern matching techniques) can be easily subverted, see the following string:

> "I've had no cranberryıng sleep for chuffıng chuffıngs days - the next door neighbour is playing classical music at full tilt!"

I have replaced the "i"'s with Turkish lower case undottted "ı"'s. Still looks pretty offensive!

Comment: Good background article. Would have probably put it as a comment rather than an answer though as it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Robin I will burn in hell, but I provided an example.

Comment: +1, Whilst it's a hard/impossible problem to solve. (I've seen arcades filled with the name CLINT due to the font used!) I would still rather see a bunch of S[Censored]horpe mistakes than a kids browser filled with obscenities.

Comment: @Robin The above approach would give "Scunthorpe" which I think is more appropriate. Children are naturally curious.

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm a big fan of Regex, I think it won't help you here. You should fetch your bad word into a string List or string Array and use `System.String.Replace` on your incoming message.

Maybe better, use `System.String.Split` and `.Join` methods:

```
string mayContainBadWords = "... bla bla ...";
string[] badWords = new string[]{"bad", "worse", "worst"};

string[] temp = string.Split(badWords, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string cleanString = string.Join("[Censored]", temp);
```

In the sample, `mayContainBadWords` is the string you want to check; `badWords` is a string array, you load from your bad word sql table and `cleanString` is your result.

Comment: which whould turn badmington into [Censored]mington

Comment: exactly! :D - but seriously, this is just a sample, not a solution ... I see no approvement in using regex, here.

Comment: and it turns "bad" to "" but not "[Censored]"

Answer (score 2):

you can use string.replace() method or RegEx class

Answer (score 1):

There is also a nice article about it which can e found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrewrea/archive/2008/05/03/bad-word-filter-with-regular-expressions.aspx)

With a little html-parsing skills, you can get a large list with swear words from [noswear](http://www.noswearing.com/dictionary/a)