# How to detect abusive comments on my website?

Tags: c#, .net

I have my website where I have given users the opportunity to share their status. How can I detect that if any abusive or slang words are used so as to block such comments?

Is there any library or trick to detect such kind of comments in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)?

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

Comment: Just don't make the clbuttic misstake to buttume that you can just replace any occurance or a word. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is not a trick; use a dictionary of bad words, and add some logic to detect "bad words" in good places. Add the ability for users to post complains about mis-correction of your logic (so you can fine tune it) and that's it.

Implementation is pretty easy, and a dictionary of "bad words" - either look it up, or write one your own.

(I used to collect bad words from customer complains on a chat service - after a year it was almost bulletproof.)

Comment: +1  Nothing spots bad words quite like the human mind, but a computer trained by those humans can come pretty close.

Comment: Some other ways to do better than the naive download-some-blacklist approach are to use Bayesian filtering (doesn't filter individual words, but groups of words, allows you to filter out many more borderline words by accepting the common legitimate uses).

Comment: Then, recognize that you don't have to treat all users equally.  If you've got some "flag as obscene" that your users use to train the filter, you can look at which users statistically get complaints (not just automated rejections).  Any foul language confirmed by a site admin can result in a permanent demerit on the account.  OTOH, an account which has generated no complaints in 3 years of activity can probably be trusted to not need filtering at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite difficult to automate and do accurately without unintended side effects. You can maintain a dictionary of bad words, and use regular expressions to replace occurrences of those bad words. Please see my answer to the following question for example code, plus some of the issues:

[Replace Bad words using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342011/replace-bad-words-using-regex/3342087#3342087)

Automated approaches have a number of shortcommings: false positives, missing bad words that are not in the dictionary, and minor variations of bad words that are not detected. Involvement from users can be used to bolster or as an alternative approach e.g SO has the abiliy to flag comments and moderators can delete or censor them.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bad word lists around which you can download and use.

eg. http://urbanoalvarez.es/blog/2008/04/04/bad-words-list/

The best thing to do is to start with a small list and add to it based on the real comments made on your site. You can put a report link on the comments so other visitors can notify you if there are bad comments made.