# Best approach of word censoring - C# 4.0

Tags: c#, keyword

For my custom made chat screen i am using the code below for checking censored words. But i wonder can this code performance improved. Thank you.

```
    if (srMessageTemp.IndexOf(" censored1 ") != -1)
        return;
    if (srMessageTemp.IndexOf(" censored2 ") != -1)
        return;
    if (srMessageTemp.IndexOf(" censored3 ") != -1)
        return;
```

C# 4.0 . actually list is a lot more long but i don't put here as it goes away.

Comment: What are you going to do when you find these words? BTW using RegEx with word boundaries is more accurate as your approach wont find " cranberry." If you want to replace words, this may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342011/replace-bad-words-using-regex/3342087#3342087.

Comment: usérs can alw@ys f|nd a way to bypass ur contr0l

Comment: L.B that is very correct but at least this helps :D chibacity i am going to look that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use LINQ or regular expression for this:

- LINQ: [How to: Query for Sentences that Contain a Specified Set of Words (LINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546163.aspx)
- Regular Expression: [Highlight a list of words using a regular expression in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653700/highlight-a-list-of-words-using-a-regular-expression-in-c-sharp)

Comment: hello. this seems like very decent solution. would this be faster ?,

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it. Here listOfCencoredWords will contains all the censored words

```
 if (listOfCensoredWords.Any(item => srMessageTemp.Contains(item)))
     return;
```

Comment: This would not limit itself to word boundaries, and it would re-search the message string for every word.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it really fast, you can use Aho-Corasick automaton. This is how antivirus software checks thousands of viruses at once. But I don't know where you can get the implementation done, so it will require much more work from you compared to using just simple slow methods like regular expressions.

See the theory here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick

Answer (score 1):

First, I hope you aren't really "tokenizing" the words as written. You know, just because someone doesn't put a space before a bad word, it doesn't make the word less bad :-) Example `,badword,`

I'll say that I would use a Regex here :-) I'm not sure if a Regex or a man-made parser would be faster, but at least a Regex would be a good starting point. As others wrote, you begin by splitting the text in words and then checking an `HashSet<string>`.

I'm adding a second version of the code, based on `ArraySegment<char>`. I speak later of this.

```
class Program
{
    class ArraySegmentComparer : IEqualityComparer<ArraySegment<char>>
    {
        public bool Equals(ArraySegment<char> x, ArraySegment<char> y)
        {
            if (x.Count != y.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }

            int end = x.Offset + x.Count;

            for (int i = x.Offset, j = y.Offset; i < end; i++, j++)
            {
                if (!x.Array[i].ToString().Equals(y.Array[j].ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(ArraySegment<char> obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;

                int end = obj.Offset + obj.Count;

                int i;

                for (i = obj.Offset; i < end; i++)
                {
                    hash *= 23;
                    hash += Char.ToUpperInvariant(obj.Array[i]);
                }

                return hash;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var rx = new Regex(@"\b\w+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        var sampleText = @"For my custom made chat screen i am using the code below for checking censored words. But i wonder can this code performance improved. Thank you.

if (srMessageTemp.IndexOf("" censored1 "") != -1)
return;
if (srMessageTemp.IndexOf("" censored2 "") != -1)
return;
if (srMessageTemp.IndexOf("" censored3 "") != -1)
return;
C# 4.0 . actually list is a lot more long but i don't put here as it goes away.

And now some accented letters àèéìòù and now some letters with unicode combinable diacritics àèéìòù";

        //sampleText += sampleText;
        //sampleText += sampleText;
        //sampleText += sampleText;
        //sampleText += sampleText;
        //sampleText += sampleText;
        //sampleText += sampleText;
        //sampleText += sampleText;

        HashSet<string> prohibitedWords = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) { "For", "custom", "combinable", "away" };

        Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var words = rx.Matches(sampleText);

        foreach (Match word in words)
        {
            string str = word.Value;

            if (prohibitedWords.Contains(str))
            {
                Console.Write(str);
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(word);
            }
        }

        sw1.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        HashSet<ArraySegment<char>> prohibitedWords2 = new HashSet<ArraySegment<char>>(
            prohibitedWords.Select(p => new ArraySegment<char>(p.ToCharArray())),
            new ArraySegmentComparer());

        var sampleText2 = sampleText.ToCharArray();

        Stopwatch sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int startWord = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < sampleText2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(sampleText2[i]) || Char.IsDigit(sampleText2[i]))
            {
                if (startWord == -1)
                {
                    startWord = i;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (startWord != -1)
                {
                    int length = i - startWord;

                    if (length != 0)
                    {
                        var wordSegment = new ArraySegment<char>(sampleText2, startWord, length);

                        if (prohibitedWords2.Contains(wordSegment))
                        {
                            Console.Write(sampleText2, startWord, length);
                            Console.Write(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine(sampleText2, startWord, length);
                        }
                    }

                    startWord = -1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (startWord != -1)
        {
            int length = sampleText2.Length - startWord;

            if (length != 0)
            {
                var wordSegment = new ArraySegment<char>(sampleText2, startWord, length);

                if (prohibitedWords2.Contains(wordSegment))
                {
                    Console.Write(sampleText2, startWord, length);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(sampleText2, startWord, length);
                }
            }
        }

        sw2.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine(sw1.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine(sw2.ElapsedTicks);
    }
}
```

I'll note that you could go faster doing the parsing "in" the original string. What does this means: if you subdivide the "document" in words and each word is put in a `string`, clearly you are creating `n` `string`, one for each word of your document. But what if you skipped this step and operated directly on the document, simply keeping the current index and the length of the current word? Then it would be faster! Clearly then you would need to create a special comparer for the `HashSet<>`.

But wait! C# has something similar... It's called [ArraySegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx). So your document would be a `char[]` instead of a `string` and each word would be an `ArraySegment<char>`. Clearly this is much more complex! You can't simply use `Regex`es, you have to build "by hand" a parser (but I think converting the `\b\w+\b` expression would be quite easy). And creating a comparer for `HashSet<char>` would be a little complex (hint: you would use `HashSet<ArraySegment<char>>` and the words to be censored would be `ArraySegment`s "pointing" to a `char[]` of a word and with size equal to the `char[].Length`, like `var word = new ArraySegment<char>("tobecensored".ToCharArray());`)

After some simple benchmark, I can see that an unoptimized version of the program using `ArraySegment<string>` is as much fast as the `Regex` version **for shorter texts**. This probably because if a word is 4-6 char long, it's as much "slow" to copy it around than it's to copy around an `ArraySegment<char>` (an `ArraySegment<char>` is 12 bytes, a word of 6 characters is 12 bytes. On top of both of these we have to add a little overhead... But in the end the numbers are comparable). But for longer texts (try decommenting the `//sampleText += sampleText;`) it becomes a little faster (10%) in Release -> Start Without Debugging (CTRL-F5)

I'll note that comparing strings character by character is **wrong**. You should always use the methods given to you by the `string` class (or by the OS). They know how to handle "strange" cases much better than you (and in Unicode there isn't any "normal" case :-) )

Comment: well you got good point about "," . yes i am replacing such characters before checking with " " . your explanation is really confusing. all i want is gaining maximum performance. gyurisc suggested linq. do you think that it would be the best ? i can certainly split the sentence to the words. but checking each word for each censored would be faster ? i can also create an hashset of strings. but would this be faster ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG If you are "replacing" characters then you are probably already doing it wrong if all you want is speed.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Updated the code. Using ArraySegment<char> has the same speed than using Regex directly for small texts, but is much more complex to write. For bigger texts it's 10% faster.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG `If you are "replacing" characters then you are probably already doing it wrong if all you want is speed.` This because manipulating a big block of text is something slow. And I hope you are prepending a space before the text and appending a space after the text, otherwise `srMessageTemp.IndexOf(" censored1 ")` won't match `"censored1"`.

Comment: thanks for answer. but i want to ask this. making a string array of words. the given sentence is maximum 140 character. then checking in a loop whether array contains any censored or not is faster or using linq would be faster ? which one ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Your question is wrong. You would have to compare arrays/lists with hashsets, or foreach with linq. You don't compare arrays with linq, because they are apples and pears. And for the benchmarks... It depends on the length of data and on many other things. You have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq for this but it's not required if you use a list to hold your list of censored values.  The solution below uses the build in list functions and allows you to do your searches case insensitive.

```
private static List<string> _censoredWords = new List<string>()
                                                  {
                                                      "badwordone1",
                                                      "badwordone2",
                                                      "badwordone3",
                                                      "badwordone4",
                                                  };


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string badword1 = "BadWordOne2";
            bool censored = ShouldCensorWord(badword1);
        }

        private static bool ShouldCensorWord(string word)
        {
            return _censoredWords.Contains(word.ToLower());
        }
```

Comment: this would not work. we are checking whether the sentence entered by user contains any bad word or not

Comment: If that is the case then you just take the sentence - use the string.Split method to create an array of strings - and pass in each string to the ShouldCensorWord method.......

Answer (score -1):

What you think about this:

```
string[] censoredWords = new[] { " censored1 ", " censored2 ", " censored3 " };

if (censoredWords.Contains(srMessageTemp))
   return;
```